# Marmalade SDK Widget

Tags: android, sdk, widget, marmalade

I'm using Marmalade SDK and I want to create an app widget. I wrote this in pure Android and now I have a problem: how to attach it to my Marmalade project? I have access to AndroidManifest.xml and there I must add a receiver section but I don't now how to attach my classes and resources to Marmalade.

Edit:
Thanks for your answer Max.

I added

> `android-manifest=AndroidManifest.xml`
>
> `android-external-res=android-external-res`
>
> `android-external-jars="libs/Widget.jar"`

to my .mkb file
and this

```
<receiver android:name="WidgetProvider" android:label="@string/widget1name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml

Now, when I start my application I haven't errors but my widget is not show on widget list.

Any ideas? Should I also use this?

> `android-custom-activity`
>
> `android-extra-application-manifest`

And how should I use it?

Edit:
Ok, I found it, section receiver sholudn't be in activity but in application. But next problem is a file R.java from my widget. Marmalade application doesn't see it. Where I have to put it? When I start my widget I get exception:
android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: can't find view: 0x...

Answer (score 0):

You need configuration options:

- android-external-jars
- android-external-res
- android-custom-activity
- android-manifest
- android-extra-application-manifest

http://developer.roolez.com/marmaladesdk/deploy/deploymenttoolsettings/configurationsettings/androidconfigurationsettings.html